# Excel: Summing if difference is less than certain time (check is done in range of values)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to sum the concurrent events which are in fixed time - want to include all events which occurred less than 2 hours prior this fixed time

[Example how it is looking and should sum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lcf7b.png)

[image]

Hopefully the description is clear - help is much appreciated.

Regards,

Jaanus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## SUMIF

In cell `C2` use this formula

```
=SUMIF(A$2:A2,">"&A2-1/12,B$2:B2)
```

and copy down.

[image]